# Always open integrated terminal with new window

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

I would like to automatically open integrated terminal when I open a new window (directory/project) in vscode. Is this possible to achieve with a setting? Tried to look for a setting on the internet but couldn't find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I think there is no settings for that but there is an extension in vscode for that: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EthanSK.restore-terminals and I think you can configure it.